why scrapy-redis recrawl the url that it has already crawled?
I have written a distributed spider using scrapy-redis.
At first, everything seemed fine.
The distributed-workers file:
# distributed-workers.py
import scrapy
from scrapy_redis.spiders import RedisSpider
from vendor_scraper.items import ProductItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class VendorSpider(RedisSpider):
    name = 'distributed-workers'
    allowed_domains = ['proxy.scrapeops.io']

    redis_key = 'url_pools:start_urls'
    
    redis_batch_size = 1  # Number of URLs to fetch from Redis at once
    max_idle_time = 7  # Number of seconds the worker can be idle before stopping
    
    # Export data format
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            'distributed_scrape_data.json': {'format': 'json', 'overwrite': True},
        },
    }
    
    # loop all pages and parse book information
    def parse(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item = ProductItem(), selector=response)
        
        l.add_value('url_item', response.url)
        l.add_css('source_page_html', 'html body h1')
        
        yield l.load_item()

# settings.py
SCHEDULER = "scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler"
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = "scrapy_redis.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter"
SCHEDULER_QUEUE_CLASS = 'scrapy_redis.queue.SpiderPriorityQueue'

However, after crawling all the URLs, one spider closed, but another didn't - and began to re-crawl the URLs that were already crawled.
Can anyone help me, and explain why?

Seems that you didn't overwrite the SCHEDULER_PERSIST setting according to your code. The SCHEDULER_PERSIST setting means whether to flush requests when closing and has a default value False.
Multiple instances of your spider share the same scheduler which includes queue and dupefilter. When SCHEDULER_PERSIST is set to False, the scheduler will be cleared when one of your spiders ends its work, and those spiders still running using the same scheduler will not know which URL has been crawled and will crawl all URLs they find.
You can set SCHEDULER_PERSIST to True in settings.py or in your spider code like:
custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            'distributed_scrape_data.json': {'format': 'json', 'overwrite': True},
        },
        'SCHEDULER_PERSIST': True
    }

Also, please check the SCHEDULER_FLUSH_ON_START setting as well, which means whether to flush scheduler on start.
